# How to get if a particular point exists in perimeter of uibeizerpath or not?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am developing an app where i am drawing a rectangle by using uibeizerpath.Its working fine .Now i want to delete that rectangle when i perform long press on that rectangle.

But the problem is i do not find any way , when i perform long press,  How to get if a particular point  exists in perimeter of uibeizerpath or not?

Answer (score 1):

[Use `-containsPoint:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBezierPath_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIBezierPath/containsPoint%3a).

```
[thatUIBezierPath containsPoint:thePoint]
```

It returns YES if thePoint is contained within thatUIBezierPath.

If you have the original CGRect of that rectangle, you could use the [CGRectContainsPoint](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGGeometry/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGRectContainsPoint) function instead, which is much more specialized and efficient.